# Async/await in useEffect hook doesn't await a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore

As the title says. I'm using firestore for my chat service. I'm attempting to set up a way to filter out messages when the firestore updates

```js
  const users = useSelector((state) => state.assignUser);

  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

  const chatID = 'KfM3GNxeVATi6sNFFUEG'

  function getIDs(messageObj){
    return messageObj.map(message => message._id)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const messagesArray = []

    db.collection('messages').doc(chatID).collection('messages').get().then(snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach(doc => messagesArray.push(doc.data()))
      setMessages(messagesArray)

      async function fetchMessages(){
        const messageIDs = await getIDs(messages)
        db.collection('messages').doc(chatID).collection('messages').onSnapshot(doc => {
          doc.forEach((document) => {
            if (messageIDs.indexOf(document.data()._id !== -1)) console.log('the is is ', messageIDs.indexOf(document.data()._id))
            else console.log('notfoundssw')
          })
        })
      }
      fetchMessages()
    })
  }, [])
```

The await doesn't await the getIDs function and the log of `messageIDs.indexOf(document.data()._id)` is -1 for every entry. I can't figure out why the async/await missbehaves

Comment: It doesn't look like there's nothing to await for since Array.prototype.map is a fully synchronous function

Comment: Mapping the ids in the `fetchMessages` would still error out and cause the logging of `messageIDs.indexOf(document.data()._id)` to be -1

Comment: There's a typo in the code, it should be: `if (messageIDs.indexOf(document.data()._id) !== -1)`

Comment: Thanks @EmileBergeron I didn't notice it. but still the original issue persists

Comment: Are you expecting `setMessages` to immediately change the value of messages? That's not how it works. It will only happen in the next render cycle. If you want to listen to changes to `messages` you need to use another useEffect. Specifically `useEffect(functionThatCallGetIds, [messages])`

Comment: See: [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54069253/1218980)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your `messagesIDs` variable depends on messages state update, which does not happen sync. Based on your code structure you would have to break in 2 `useEffects`. The first one that updates messages on mount and the second that listens to messages updates:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const messagesArray = []

    db.collection('messages').doc(chatID).collection('messages').get().then(snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach(doc => messagesArray.push(doc.data()))
      setMessages(messagesArray)
    })
  }, [])


  useEffect(() => {
    // check if messages is not empty
    if(!messages.length) return

    const messageIDs = getIDs(messages) // your getIDs is not async, so no need to await
    db.collection('messages').doc(chatID).collection('messages').onSnapshot(doc => {
      doc.forEach((document) => {
        if (messageIDs.indexOf(document.data()._id) !== -1) {
          console.log('the is is ', messageIDs.indexOf(document.data()._id))
        } else {
          console.log('notfoundssw')
        }
      })
    })
}, [messages])
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I can fully understand how you're getting data, but setting state is actually asynchronous so you cannot guarantee all your state data is updated by the time you execute `map`.

I would break up your `useEffect` into two different ones.

The second one which will contain the `fetchMessages` call should use 'messages' as part of its dependency array, i.e. it will execute once your 'messages' state has been updated.